# How to sum up values of 'D' column for every row with the same combination of values from columns 'A','B' and 'C?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply, nan

I need to **sum up values of 'D' column for every row with the same combination of values from columns 'A','B' and 'C**. Eventually I need to create DataFrame with unique combinations of values from
columns 'A','B' and 'C' with corresponding sum in column D.

```
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,3,size=(10,4)),columns=list('ABCD'))
df

OT:
    A   B   C   D
0   0   2   0   2
1   0   1   2   1
2   0   0   2   0
3   1   2   2   2
4   0   2   2   2
5   0   2   2   2
6   2   2   2   1
7   2   1   1   1
8   1   0   2   0
9   1   2   0   0
```

I've tried to create temporary data frame with empty cells

```
D = pd.DataFrame([i for i in range(len(df))]).rename(columns = {0:'D'})
D['D'] = ''
D 

OT:
    D
0   
1   
2   
3   
4   
5   
6   
7   
8   
9
```

And use apply() to sum up all 'D' column values for unique row consisted of columns 'A','B' and 'C'. For example below line returns sum of values from 'D' column for 'A'=0,'B'=2,'C'=2:

```
df[(df['A']==0) & (df['B']==2) & (df['C']==2)]['D'].sum()

OT:
4
```

function:

```
def Sumup(cols):
    A = cols[0]
    B = cols[1]
    C = cols[2]
    D = cols[3]
    
    sum = df[(df['A']==A) & (df['B']==B) & (df['C']==C)]['D'].sum()
    
    return sum
```

apply on df and saved in temp df D['D']:

```
D['D'] = df[['A','B','C','D']].apply(Sumup)
```

Later I wanted to use drop_duplicates but I receive dataframe consisted of NaN's.

```
D
OT:
D
0   NaN
1   NaN
2   NaN
3   NaN
4   NaN
5   NaN
6   NaN
7   NaN
8   NaN
9   NaN
```

Anyone could give me a hint how to manage the NaN problem or what other approach can I apply to solve the original
problem?

Comment: Use `groupby` on a combination of the first three columns.

Comment: [pandas groupby documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.groupby(['A','B','C']).sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,3,size=(10,4)),columns=list('ABCD'))

df.groupby(["A", "B", "C"])["D"].sum()
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.